# NullPointerException when publishing a Grails 3 plugin

Tags: grails

I'm trying to publish [this Grails 3](https://github.com/domurtag/grails-simple-captcha/tree/grails3) plugin to Bintray, by following the steps in [this guide](https://medium.com/@benorama/how-to-publish-your-grails-3-plugin-to-bintray-c341b24f567d). The final step is to run

```
gradle bintrayUpload
```

on the command-line from the project root dir. When I do this, I get the following error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency.add(DefaultTaskDependency.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$11.run(AbstractTask.java:327)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator.mutate(TaskMutator.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.dependsOn(AbstractTask.java:325)
    at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayPlugin$_apply_closure2_closure5.doCall(BintrayPlugin.groovy:96)
    at com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayPlugin$_apply_closure2.doCall(BintrayPlugin.groovy:88)
```

Any ideas about what the cause of the problem is?

### Update

Following the suggestions below, I've made the following changes in [build.gradle](https://github.com/domurtag/grails-simple-captcha/blob/grails3/build.gradle)

- updated the bintray plugin to version 1.2
- changed `group "org.grails.plugins"` to `group "domurtag.plugins"`

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'.
>
> > Could not create package 'grails/plugins/org.grails.plugins:grails-simple-captcha': HTTP/1.1
> >     403 Forbidden [message:forbidden]

I've added these environment variables

```
BINTRAY_USER=domurtag
BINTRAY_KEY=my_api_key
```

The error message suggests that the reason for the 403 is because an attempt is being made to publish the plugin to the `grails/plugins` repository (which I don't have access to), but I don't know why this is happening?

Comment: You could check/ compare your setting with my [project setup](https://github.com/stefanfreitag/LedBorg)

Comment: If you are still stuck with the message:forbidden problem, please try to create the package manually at bintray. After this try to use the bintrayUpload task to upload your artifacts.

Comment: @StefanFreitag when I run `grails package-plugin`, should I upload the generated `.tar` or `.zip`?

Comment: Hi Dónal, I am not so familiar with Grails...:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw the exactly same stacktrace for my Gradle builds. My Gradle build script made use of `com.jfrog.bintray` version 1.1. After upgrading to version 1.2 the build runs successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
Could not create package 'grails/plugins/org.grails.plugins:grails-simple-captcha': HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden [message:forbidden]
```

Is because you are trying to publish to the `grails/plugins` repository which you do not have permission to publish to. You have to modify the `build.gradle` bintray configuration to publish to your own repository. Example:

```
version "0.1"
group "benorama.plugins"
bintray {
  pkg {
    userOrg = '' // If you want to publish to an organization
    name = "benorama.plugins:$project.name"
    issueTrackerUrl = "https://github.com/benorama/grails-$project.name/issues"
    vcsUrl = “https://github.com/benorama/grails-$project.name"
    version {
      attributes = ['grails-plugin': "benorama.plugins:$project.name"]
      name = project.version
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have published to your own repository you can request to have your plugin included in `grails/plugins`

See this tutorial for good guide: https://medium.com/@benorama/how-to-publish-your-grails-3-plugin-to-bintray-c341b24f567d

Comment: In `build.gradle` I changed `group "org.grails.plugins"` to `group "domurtag.plugins"` but I still get a 403 error when I run `gradle bintrayUpload`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your bintray config in build.gradle.
By default the Bintray Gradle plugin is configured with external files:

```
// Used for publishing to central repository, remove if not needed
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/grailsCentralPublishing.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle'
```

so you must override this config by putting your config afterwards, e.g.:

```
// Used for publishing to central repository, remove if not needed
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/grailsCentralPublishing.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle'

version '0.1'
group 'org.grails.plugins'

bintray {
    pkg {
        userOrg = '<your bintray username>'
        repo = 'plugins'
        name = "org.grails.plugins:$project.name"
        desc = "Grails $project.name plugin"
        websiteUrl = "http://grails.org/plugin/$project.name"
        issueTrackerUrl = "https://github.com/<username>/grails-$project.name/issues"
        vcsUrl = "https://github.com/<username>/grails-$project.name"
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        version {
            attributes = ['grails-plugin': "org.grails.plugins:$project.name"]
            name = project.version
        }
    }
}
```

in your case the value of `userOrg` is not set (userOrg `grails` is used), so you are not allowed to upload to `https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/...`

in addition you can check `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle` to see full bintray config.