# Grails (3.0.8) plugin bintrayUpload returns HTTP/1.1 - forbidden

Tags: grails, plugins, publish, grails-plugin, bintray

bintrayUpload always try to publish my plugin to grails/plugins instead my repo danieltribeiro/plugins. And I got a 403 forbidden because of that.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'.
> Could not create package 'grails/plugins/my-plugin': HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden [message:forbidden]
```

I checked the answer here to a similar problem [NullPointerExcpetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808826/nullpointerexception-when-publishing-a-grails-3-plugin) and tried all the solutions proposed without lucky. Including the  [Graeme Rocher Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808826/nullpointerexception-when-publishing-a-grails-3-plugin#answer-30864682) just changing the name and leaving userRepo in blank. But no matter what I do the task aways try to upload to grails.plugins repo.

My bintray plugin is 1.2

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.2"
}
```

I tried a lot of configs inside bintray closure on build.gradle following the [Benoit tutorial](https://medium.com/@benorama/how-to-publish-your-grails-3-plugin-to-bintray-c341b24f567d). I created the plugins repo, configured env vars BINTRAY_USER and BINTRAY_KEY with correct values (otherwise it throwns a 401-Unauthorized)

Here is my last (not working) configuration.

```
version "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
group "danieltribeiro.plugins" // Or your own user/organization

bintray {
  pkg {
    userOrg = 'danieltribeiro' // If you want to publish to an organization
    repo = 'plugins'
    name = "${project.name}"
    //issueTrackerUrl = "https://github.com/benorama/grails-$project.name/issues"
    //vcsUrl = "https://github.com/benorama/grails-$project.name"
    version {
      attributes = ['grails-plugin': "${project.group}:${project.name}"]
      name = project.version
    }
  }
}
```

Why this task continues to POST to grails.plugins?

Comment: See [this recent blog post](http://blog.agileorbit.com/2015/10/07/Publishing-Grails-3-Plugins.html) which has more current information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probally you are using:

```
apply from:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle'
```

It take the default bintray config.

Override this config or comment it and do manually:

```
bintray {
    user = 'user'
    key = '*****'
    pkg {    
        userOrg = '' // 
        repo = 'nameRepo'
        licenses = project.hasProperty('license') ? [project.license] :['Apache-2.0']
        name = "$project.name"
        issueTrackerUrl = "yourGitHub"
        vcsUrl = "yourGitHub"
        version {
            attributes = ['grails-plugin': "$project.group:$project.name"]
            name = project.version
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robson. It helped me but it's not working yet. Now the task create a package and version on my repository but don't upload any file. I tried to add publications = ['maven'] but I get the error: Could not find publication: maven

Comment: Just comment - apply from...bintrayPublishing.gradle